# How to format multiseries column 2D Fusion Chart tooltip String

Tags: javascript, charts, fusioncharts

The default Tooltip formating for Fusion Chart is :

```
Series Name, X-axis Label, y-axis value
```

I want to format it like:

```
X axis Label\n
Series 1 Name: Series 1 Y axis Value
Series 2 Name: Series 2 Y axis Value
```

and so on ..

Is there any way to format the tooltip as like HighChart Tooltip formatter?

Comment: To set a custom tool tip or to override the default format, use "tooltext" attribute of the <set> element.  For example: <set value='27400' toolText='Jan {br} 2006 : 27400' />

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. However if I have data conatins 10K points, then I need to override tooltip text for all points. Is there any formatter method, as like in Highchart. I'm specially look for such one so I need to change only some few lines of my JS code.

Comment: Seems like we're working on thus exact same thing for our upcoming release. If you're interested to try out a beta, send our support an email citing this post.

Comment: Do vote for answer if my solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are looking for is not possible using data configuration alone and is being planned for coming releases.

A very neat workaround is to use the `beforeDataUpdate` event and add toolText programmatically to the data.

You can get details of FusionCharts events at http://docs.fusioncharts.com/maps/Contents/javascript/API/events.html

Comment: Do you have any examples of this?